# Is it possible to have stunnel listen to specific path?

Tags: unix, connection, https, tls, stunnel

I am able to configure Stunnel to listen for 'myserver:port', however I'd like to be able to have Stunnel listen for a specific path e.g. 'myserver:port/path'

Does anyone happen to know if this is possible?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. A TCP port is not associated with a path.

Depending on what you want to achieve, a HTTPS server/proxy may work for you.